# Slackbotを日本語で利用する場合

Tags: slack

SlackのCustomize Your TeamのSlackbotについて質問です。
日本語でキーワードを登録すると、その単語を含む場合にうまく返答されないようです。
たとえば、When someone saysに「喫煙所」と登録すると、「喫煙所はどこ？」には回答できず、「喫煙所」と入力しないと、Slackbot respondsの「9Fにあります」に回答できないようです。これを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問者さんの想定する動作を実現する方法はないかと思われます。
登録した単語を含む文章であっても、該当単語と他単語の間にスペースや特定の文字(例えば「?」「！」等)での区切りがない場合は認識されないようです。

[image: image01]

上図のように登録した状態で「where is smoking area?」と発言するとレスポンスは返ってくるので「?」等の記号は区切り文字として認識されるようです。
(スペース・記号に関しては全角半角関係なし)

[image: image2]